# SharePoint 2013 list version history summary

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, version-history

I would like to check if there is an option(without using a third party software) to pull a summary of SharePoint 2013 list item version history. the SharePoint OOB option enables to check item by item only, not user-friendly at all. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this-

```
 if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) 
 {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
 }
 $web = Get-SPWeb http://webUrl
 $list = $web.GetList("Provide ListName")
 $item = $list.GetItemById(Provide Item ID)
 foreach($version in $item.Versions)
 {
   Write-Host $item.Name "'s version" $version.VersionLabel "has been Modified by" $version.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName ":: URL ->" $item.Url -ForegroundColor Green
 }
```

Please refer to the following articles

[SharePoint 2013 Retrieve the List Item Version History](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-web-services/)

[Retrieve The List Item Version Histor](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/sharepoint-2013-retrieve-the-list-item-version-history-and/)y

Answer (score 0):

If versioning is needed for admin of site or library you can think of writing reusable power-shell script to generate excel file with all document related versioning history.

Generate a report in excel format which includes information like:

- Site Collection Title
- Site Name
- Library
- File Name
- File URL
- File Type
- Last Modified Date
- Number of Versions
- Latest Version Size
- Version Size
- Total size

You can check the technical details on the link below. It is beautifully explained how to achieve above report generated site collection wise using power-shell

Reference : [PowerShell Script To Get SharePoint Document Versioning Report](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/powershell-script-to-get-sharepoint-document-versioning-repo/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following PowerShell commands to retrieve all versions including comments, the user who creates the version and so on for all items and report the data in a .csv file.

```
# ******* Variables Section ******************
#Define these variables 
$WebURL="<site>"
$ListName ="<list/library name>"
$ReportFile = "C:\temp\Invoice_VersionHistory.csv"
# *********************************************
#delete file if exists
If (Test-Path $ReportFile)
{
Remove-Item $ReportFile
}
#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName) 
 #Check if list exists
if($List -ne $null)
{
  #Get all list items
  $ItemsColl = $List.Items
  #Write Report Header
  Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value "Item ID, Version Lable, Created by, Created at, Title"
  #Loop through each item
  foreach ($item in $ItemsColl) 
  {
   #Iterate each version
      foreach($version in $item.Versions)
       {
    #Get the version content
    $VersionData = "$($item.id), $($version.VersionLabel), $($version.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName), $($version.Created), $($version['Title'])"
    #Write to report
    Add-Content -Path $ReportFile -Value $VersionData
   }
  }

}
Write-Host "Version history has been exported successfully!"
```

If you wants to get all item version for all lists/libraries in the site, you can iterate lists/libraries.

Demos:

[Export SharePoint List Item Version History to Excel](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/sharepoint-version-history-export-to-excel.html)

[List Item Versions using PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19104.sharepoint-2010-list-and-delete-list-item-versions-using-powershell.aspx)